# Responder e pedir para fechar é uma pratica ruim?

Tags: debate, suporte, perguntas, escopo-do-site

Geralmente eu solicito o fechamentos de perguntas que aparentam estar fora do escopo e adiciono um comentário de orientação para o usuário com uma provável "resposta" (se possível).

Porém eu estava pensando, se a pergunta for suportada http://superuser.com talvez eu deve-se recomendar ele postar lá e fechar a pergunta no SOpt, mas não acho legal recomendar o usuário a visitar um site em um idioma que talvez ele não esteja familiarizado (se bem que com [google-tradutor](https://translate.google.com) já poderia ajuda-lo).

Ao invés disto, então me veio a ideia, eu poderia responder a pergunta e solicitar o fechamento dela a seguir e quem sabe em um futuro próximo quando a proposta do SUpt for aprovada (*SE* aprovada) poderíamos migra-lá para lá?

Qual destas ações seria mais saudável para o SOpt em casos de questões fora do escopo, mas que tem suporte em outras comunidades do SE?

1. Comentar dizendo qual a melhor comunidade para se perguntar isto e fechar a questão.
2. Comentar com uma breve resposta (se possível) e fechar a questão.
3. Responder a duvida e fechar a questão em seguida.

Comment: Relacionado: [Responder perguntas que foram negativadas, é ruim?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1246/3117)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Acho que devemos respeitar o que está no escopo e fechar o que está fora do escopo.

Se uma pergunta está fora de escopo devemos fechá-la sem resposta. Se é possível ajudar o AP indicando a comunidade certa (ainda que noutra lingua) acho isso preferível. Se quem comenta souber a resposta e couber como comentário é simpático.

No fundo é uma mistura das tuas 3 possibilidades. O que acho mais importante é respeitar-mos o escopo do site, que somos nós que decidimos. Se um dia quisermos mudar podemos fazê-lo se a maioria concordar.

Comment: Concordo com o ponto de vista do Sérgio